# Iterating a huge std::vector of std::vectors and modifying elements

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

I have to iterate a huge std::vector vec, it is defined as follows:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec;
```

Since I have to modify elements of `vec` multiple times depends on `flag`  I have to create another vector as follows:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> eVecTemp;
```

And how I am populating `eVecTemp` is  shown below:

```
for(auto &x: vec)
 {
    bool flag= false;
    std::vector<int> pers_vec(x);
    int arry[]={4,5,6,7}
    while(i < 4)
    {
        int candidate=arr[i];   

        if( !flag )
        {
            x.push_back(candidate);
            flag=true;                        
        }
        std::vector<int> new_vec(pers_vec);
        new_vec.push_back(candidate);
        eVecTemp.emplace_back(new_vec);
       ++i;
    }

}
```

I feel there may be better implementation possible for the following snippet, any suggestions please.

```
std::vector<int> new_vec(pers_vec);
new_vec.push_back(candidate);
eVecTemp.emplace_back(new_vec);
```

Comment: What're you trying to accomplish Your `while (i < 4)` loop is either infinite or never entered.

Comment: Well you might save up time by not reallocating a vector for storing just one more int than x. You end up making a full copy of x every time.

Comment: please correct at least your typos.

Comment: @Barry while loop is intend to iterate over `arry[]`

Comment: Where do you reset flag?

Comment: @MikeMB code is added to reset flag

Comment: @Praetorian there is a reason to keep pers_vec as it is until while loop over. So I created a new_vec

Comment: I understand now (your code is hard to follow because of your variable names). In any case, you should `eVecTemp.push_back(std::move(new_vec));`. And instead of copying `pers_vec` into `new_vec` upon construction, first reserve room in `new_vec` for `pers_vec.size() + 1`, and then add `pers_vec` and `candidate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your code is equivalent to:

```
eVecTemp.reserve(vec.size() * 4);
for (auto& x : vec)
{
    for (int i : {4,5,6,7}) {
        eVecTemp.push_back(x);
        eVecTemp.back().push_back(i);
    }

    x.push_back(4);
}
```

That'll also be a lot faster since there will be much fewer copies made - you are currently copying `x` into `pers_vec`, then copying that again into `new_vec`, then copying that again into `eVecTemp`. I'm saving you two copies per inner loop.

Comment: Does not make more sense if we use emplace_back instead  of first push_back inside the inner loop?

Comment: @Steephen They'd do the same thing. `emplace` only adds value if you're in-place constructing an object (say if we did `emplace_back(x.begin(), x.end())`)

Comment: Just wanted to confirme that this is correct - I ended up with almost exactly the same version.

Answer (score 0):

What I see here is that you are probably losing a lot of time making a copy of x at every loop.

```
    std::vector<int> new_vec(pers_vec);
    new_vec.push_back(candidate);
    eVecTemp.emplace_back(new_vec);
```

`pers_vec` contains `x` (except if `flag` was true but in this case the difference is still minor). I am pretty confident you could rewrite your code to avoid using it at all. Since it seems some parts of your code are missing I am not sure exactly what you would need to change.

I believe you could use this constructor for your `vector`:

```
 vector( InputIt first, InputIt last,
    const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

In this case `first` would be `x.begin()` and `last` would change depending on what you're doing with your flag and loop which I don't really understand.

Answer (score 0):

My problem can't be explained correctly in my question, so I will  take partial answer from Barry's answer and rewrote as follows:

```
new_vec.push_back(pers_vec);
eVecTemp.back().push_back(candidate);
```